# How to use Youtube Player API on a handlebar template?

Tags: javascript, express, video, youtube-api, handlebars.js

I have an express app that dynamically embeds a YouTube video every time the page is requested. I wanted to use the YouTube Player API to reload the page when the video finishes playing.

The problem is that on [the YouTube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) the given example uses Javascript to embed the video and from what I've read I can't use handlebars to render a script tag. (Or can I?)

Is there any way to use the API for an already embedded iFrame? Or how else can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Is it just a straight page refresh when the video finishes? Or are you trying to do something more complex like change what video is embedded in the page after the video finishes playing? Sample code would be helpful too.

Comment: Just a simple refresh. The video change is already working on my server.